# ANTLR4 skip no difference with or without

Tags: antlr4

I do not see what skip does; this is the example

```
FS : WHITESPACE* (',') WHITESPACE*;
WHITESPACE : [ \r\t\n]+ ->skip;
```

When I run with ANTLRWorks2 in TestRig I see no difference between with or without `->skip`. The visual tree contains (i will use normal dot `.` for space) `.,.\r\n`

What is the difference between using or not using `->skip`?

Comment: 'WS' is the same as 'WHITESPACE'?

Answer (score 2):

Space chars on their own will be skipped, but not when they surround comma's. If you want them to be skipped, do not include them in your `FS` rule:

```
FS : ',';
WHITESPACE : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip;
```